# Testing an app on notch devices emulators

Tags: android, android-emulator

We have an android mobile app that needs to be tested on all android devices to check if there are any design issues. We have tested the app using the android emulators provided by "Android Studio". But we also need to test the same application in the Notch devices also. But in android studio, notch type devices are not available for us to test the application

Can you please suggest on how a notch device emulator can be created and tested?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use PIXEL 3 XL device in the emulator itself. This device has a notch display.[image]

[image]

Comment: There is no such device in the Android Virtual Device Manager of Android Studio. How did you get this device?

Comment: it's there in the  Android Virtual Device Manager. have you updated your studio?

Comment: What version of android studio you are using? I am using android studio 3.3.2 version

Comment: yeah i am able to see the device now.

Comment: How can we detect which drawables and layout a particular device is using in android studio?

Answer (score 3):

If you create emulator of API > P(28), you can enable it from setting. Here I have provided step by step guild.

https://medium.com/@hiteshdhamshaniya.wvmagic/notch-android-emulator-with-p-e9b3556d9d5e

or

[Here is step by step video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vVQp_yXtH7E)

First thing first, you need to have android P emulator.

Start Android Pie Emulator

Go to Settings -> System

System → Advance → Developer option.

If you can not find developer option, you need to enable it via several clicks on build number.

Go to System → About emulated device → Build number.

Once enable developer option, follow below steps

Developer options → Simulate a display with a cutout

Now you can find different notch (cutout) options there.

Answer (score 2):

You can test in Firebase Test Lab. For all Samsung devices, go to Samsung Remote Test Lab.  Here are the links -

Firebase test lab -

https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/?&gclid=CjwKCAjw9dboBRBUEiwA7VrrzfvVUAuPjiMaHlDv0nNrwfRtgnkz8jo9d2aaDI8-lbTBhbK47F4U0RoClMoQAvD_BwE

For Samsung -

https://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlFAQ.action

Comment: How can i add my project to Firebase test lab?

Comment: Just drop the apk and test